# Custom wallpaper set up through system settings shows up as black

Tags: desktop, wallpaper

Using the system settings app to set a custom wallpaper (from my own images, not the ones that are pre-installed with elementary) makes the active wallpaper black instead of changing to the requested image.

Using a file browser, right clicking an image and hitting "Set as Desktop Background" works just fine.

Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug.
I've submitted the report.

Please, follow [the link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1672065) and tell that you are affected too!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. The workaround is to copy the image you wish to use into `/usr/share/backgrounds` and they will show up in the background options.